# Make figure and table not moveble in IEEE ACCESS template

Tags: ieeeaccess

I am using the IEEE Access template to prepare my manuscript. I do not want the images to auto-fit, and I want to keep my figures and tables where their commands are written. I am using \begin{figure*}[H] with \usepackage{float}, but it makes the figure disappear. Is there any way to prevent the figure from being movable?

Comment: Hi, welcome! Full-width figures in two columns documents can only be placed at the top of the page, for a lot of (reasonable in my opinion) reasons. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632031/38080

Comment: Mandatory reading (long, but very important if you want to "grok" floating (figures, table, etc.) in LaTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: Is there any way to fix the page then?

Comment: See "Double-column floats are always deferred first" in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat. Basically, at the end of your work, you can move the `figure*` around until you got what you want (remember to compile twice each time around). There is no direct method, at least not in LaTeX.

Comment: An additional comment: if you think about submitting the paper at the end, don't do that. They will reformat your article with something that's not LaTeX anyway, and they'll decide the figure positions, so... spare yourself the struggle 

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.